# How Convert SQL CE 3.5 database to SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sql-server-ce

I started a project using SQL CE 3.5 in Visual Studio 10. But now I found out that the database is very slow. I did some testing on SQLite and thi is much faster.

Is there a way that I easily can convert de SQL CE 3.5 (sdf) database to SQLite?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have a tool to "dump" an entire SQL Compact file as SQL script, that you can then run against a SQLite db - http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: i have downloaded export2sqlce.zip but how to use it ?

Comment: https://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Command%20line%20utilities&referringTitle=Documentation

Answer (score 2):

1. Export CSV file(s) from SQL CE, import into SQLite, or
2. Use ODBC to connect to both databases and move data from one to the other