# Can i convert sdf db file to sqlite db file and use in android.?

Tags: android

I am having a sdf file with me.i want to use that database file in my android app by converting it to sqlite3 db file is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

See http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com ala [How Convert SQL CE 3.5 database to SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303797/how-convert-sql-ce-3-5-database-to-sqlite) (Duplicate)